# How to prevent page from refreshing on selection of First Drop Down List value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have Two 'DropDownLists' which I want to Fill with the help of first 'DropDownList'. I have successfully filled both 'DropDownLists' but when I select the value from the first 'DropDownList', my page refreshes every time. Please help me. What should I do or how to prevent page form refreshing?

Comment: Show your aspx code. Have you set `AutoPostBack=true` on the first? Why you don't want that? I thought you want to update the second according to the selected item in the first(cascading dropdowns).

Comment: Yes I have set AutoPostBack =True. Because instead of that Second DropDownList do not fill or fetch value.

Comment: Is it webforms or mvc ?

Comment: It is webform Not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the second `DropDownList` on client-side using AJAX, instead of server-side to avoid postback

**Ajax**

```
$('#firstDropDown').change(function() {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "yourCodebehind.aspx/yourMethod"
        data: '{arg: "' + $('#firstDropDown').val() + '" }',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                $('#secondDropDown').append('<option>'+result.d[i]+'</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

**yourCodebehind.aspx**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static Array yourMethod(var arg)
{
    //Fetch your data
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax update panel for unwanted refreshing the page 
the scriptmanager use in body tag.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and then use following code .

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

use javascript

```
$(".firstdropdown").change(function()
{
    var value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: './ajax/value.php?firstdropdown='+value,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#seconddropdown").val(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is C#, not PHP and Ajax, not javascript

Comment: Yes I Want this for Asp.net and C#.

Comment: I know you want C#, but he is suggesting javascript which is more nature attempt in web development for client side scripting. An alternative to ASP.NET WebForms traditional method.